# VBA InputBox Display

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox, msgbox

I don't really know if someone can understand. But what I'm trying to do is this... I want to store two or more values in an inputbox so when a user types in any of the data, it'll given a response I've stored but if not, it'll give a response such as "I can't really detect your school at the moment" as in the code below

```
Sub MessageBox_shortSurvey()
Dim name As Variant
Dim welcome As Variant
Dim department As Variant
Dim iwe As Variant
Dim Level As Integer
Output = MsgBox("Hello! I'm Fortunate's Personal Assistant Bot" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Are You Interested In Taking A Short Survey With Me?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Short Survey")
If Output = vbYes Then
    MsgBox "Great! I'll Guide You Through This"
    name = InputBox("First Question, What's Your Name?")
    If name <> "" Then
        welcome= MsgBox("                     Welcome " & name & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " Would you like to continue with the survey?", vbYesNo)
            If Continue = vbYes Then
                Level = InputBox("What Level Are You Currently?")
                MsgBox "Nice One!"
                department = InputBox("What department?")
                iwe = MsgBox("Wow! That's nice, you must be an iwe!", vbYesNo)
                If iwe = vbYes Then
                    one = MsgBox("You have one more question to go, continue?", vbYesNo)
                    If one = vbYes Then
                        school = InputBox("Which state is your school located?")
                        MsgBox "Thank You, I've taken note of all your information"
                        result = MsgBox("Do You Want To View Result Now?", vbYesNo)
                        If result = vbYes Then
                            MsgBox "Inna Moment..."
                            MsgBox "This is a bio of you, based on my intelligence and your info supplied"
                            MsgBox "Your Name is " & name
                            MsgBox "You're in " & Level & " level," & " a Student of " & department & " Department"
                            If school = "Ondo" & school = "Lagos" Then
                            'just before this, I'm trying to pick from any two values that are typed in the textbox,
                            'such that when user inputs from any two stored values the system will return a given response
                                MsgBox "From the look of things, you must be from FUTA, The Federal University of Technology, Akure"
                            Else
                            MsgBox "I can't really detect your school at the moment"
                            End If
                        Else
                            MsgBox "Thank You For All Your Information, I'm Always Here For You, Goodbye!"
                        End If
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Thank you for holding on, You Can Always Try Again"
                    End If
                Else
                MsgBox "Thanks for participating"
                End If
            End If
        Else
    End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Thanks! But you can try again if you change your mind"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: @BigBen I'm trying to store two values in an input box such that when a user types in any two of them, it can display a stored response

Comment: @Warcupine yeah, I'll correct that

Comment: So how do I go around this now? @BigBen

Comment: What do you mean by "display a stored response"? Sounds like you might want to use a userform here if you're dealing with multiple inputs.

Comment: So if someone enters Engineering Department and Massachusetts you want it to say something about MIT? (As an example)

Comment: Yeah, something like that @warcupine

Comment: If you look at the code well,  I'm trying to add two values to that "school" variable,  and the values are "ondo" and "lagos" @bigben

Comment: `school` can't be both `"ondo"` and `"lagos"` though at the same time... it can be one *or* the other?